# CSS Layout liquid column issue wrapping content

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|.....................................................|
|..header height: 128px...............................|
|.....................................................|
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|.............|.......................................|
|.sidebar.....|..Lorem ipsum..........................|
|.width:......|.......................................|
|.140px.......|..+---------------------------------------------+
|.............|..|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|.............|..|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|.............|..|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|.............|..|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|.............|..+---------------------------------------------+
|.............|.......................................|
|.............|.......................................|
|.............|.......................................|
|.............|..frame should be as large as the......|
|.............|..entire viewport or larger depending..|
|.............|..on the context.......................|
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to create a 2 column layout (sidebar + content area) with a header (and possibly a footer) where the sidebar has a fixed width and the content area is fluid.
The difficulty is having the content area effectively wrap its contents so the content doesn't overflow.

I'd like to know if there is a CSS way to do this and if not whats the best Javascript approach to it since I had some difficulties with cross-browser support.

Comment: is your ASCII drawing trying to depict the desired result, or is the 'xxxx'-area breaking out of its container the problem you're trying to fix?

Comment: It might also be nice to show some actual code/content so we know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: The ASCII is the div breaking the container (what shouldn't happen).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#content {
  margin-top: 128px;
  maring-left: 140px;
}
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 128px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

Comment: position: fixed does not work in IE < 7 - plus you really wouldn't need that for this layout as float would be more than capable of positioning that sidebar in the right place

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#element { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
   height: 128px;
}

#sidebar {
   float: left;
   width: 140px;
}

#content {
   margin-left: 140px;
}
```

You can see [an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/xCerg/1/).

Comment: This css is similar to the one I use and as such causes the issue.

Comment: What is the HTML/CSS for the element that's escaping the `#content`?  The above CSS has worked fine for me on several projects, so there must be something unique about your escaping element.

Comment: Any block element with width larger than the available width, considering the #content is browser wide...

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to contain an element like that is to set a min-width on your `#content`  container that will ensure it's always wide enough to contain its large block level elements.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion and now I am attempting a javascript solution. Will post progress.

Answer (score 0):

After having researched the matter substantially, I've concluded that it simply can't be done with css in a compatible way (and I'm not even considering IE6). The possible solutions involve either javascript or tables.
I picked the lesser evil (tables) since javascript resulted in a more complicated solution and handling the onResize event can be taxing on the browser depending on the complexity of the function called.
Certain search engine concerns are not important given it's an intranet application.
The only real issue is accessibility.

I'd be quite glad to be proven wrong though :)